# Socket.io client can't receive data from the server after refreshing the page

Tags: angularjs, socket.io

I am trying to add socket.io 1.0 into my angularjs web app. I have two views in the angularjs, the socket listeners are defined in the first view. In the first view they can always receive messages from the socket server with or without refreshing the page.

However when I go to the second view, the client can only receive the message for the first time. If I refresh the second view, close the server with ctrl + C and restart it, the client can't receive & print the data. It did reconnect to the socket server, and the server did send the message. I confirmed it by printing the connection info and it showed that the "connected" is true before the message was sent. I also tried something like 'force new connection':true, but it did not work.

Here are my code:

The server end:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = module.exports = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
// Hook Socket.io into Express
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
// Socket.io Communication
var socket = require('./scripts/socket.js');
// io.sockets.on('connection', socket);
//The code below are added for testing socket.io of prodApp
var job = "{\"id\": 554120,\"name\": \"vidhyachrometest\", \"facility_id\": 2,\"location\": [], \"staff\": [],\"log\": []}";
var dataJob = JSON.parse(job);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('connection', socket);
    socket.emit('job:received', dataJob);   
    console.log('Message sent');
});

server.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", this.address().port, app.settings.env);
});
```

The client end:
Service.js

```
angular.module('starter.services', ['LocalStorageModule'])
.factory('socket', function($rootScope){
    /* Locate socket IO server via the ip and port*/
    var socket = io.connect("http://127.0.0.1:3000");
    socket.on('connect', function(){alert("Connect")});
    socket.on('reconnect', function(){alert("Reconnect")});
    socket.on('reconnecting', function(){alert("Reconnecting")});
    return {
        on: function(eventName, callback) {
            socket.on(eventName, function() {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    callback.apply(socket, args);
                });
            });
        },
        emit: function(eventName, data, callback) {
            socket.emit(eventName, data, function() {
                var args = arguments;
                $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                    if (callback) {
                        callback.apply(socket, args);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
})
```

Controller.js

```
var url = 'data/jobs.json';
//Socket.io listeners
//Assume the data is a json object of a new job to a specific facility
socket.on('job:received', function(data){
    alert(data);
    httpCache.add(url, data);
    // alert("after: " + JSON.parse(cachedJobs[1]).length);     
    if($scope.user.role_id == localStorageService.get('Manager')){
        Helpers.incrementPendingnum();
        $rootScope.pendingnum = localStorageService.get('pendingnum');
        data.pending = "Pending";
        $rootScope.jobs.push(data);
        localStorageService.set("joblist", $rootScope.jobs);
    }
});
```

If you need, this is the info of the connection:

```
connection { nsp:
   { name: '/',
     server:
      { nsps: [Object],
        _path: '/socket.io',
        _serveClient: true,
        _adapter: [Function: Adapter],
        _origins: '*:*',
        sockets: [Circular],
        eio: [Object],
        engine: [Object] },
     sockets: [ [Circular] ],
     connected: { GLhGYMCy2FAXCYUXAAAA: [Circular] },
     fns: [],
     ids: 0,
     acks: {},
     adapter: { nsp: [Circular], rooms: [Object], sids: [Object], encoder: {} },

     _events: { connection: [Function] } },
  server:
   { nsps: { '/': [Object] },
     _path: '/socket.io',
     _serveClient: true,
     _adapter: [Function: Adapter],
     _origins: '*:*',
     sockets:
      { name: '/',
        server: [Circular],
        sockets: [Object],
        connected: [Object],
        fns: [],
        ids: 0,
        acks: {},
        adapter: [Object],
        _events: [Object] },
     eio:
      { clients: [Object],
        clientsCount: 1,
        pingTimeout: 60000,
        pingInterval: 25000,
        upgradeTimeout: 10000,
        maxHttpBufferSize: 100000000,
        transports: [Object],
        allowUpgrades: true,
        allowRequest: [Function],
        cookie: 'io',
        ws: [Object],
        _events: [Object] },
     engine:
      { clients: [Object],
        clientsCount: 1,
        pingTimeout: 60000,
        pingInterval: 25000,
        upgradeTimeout: 10000,
        maxHttpBufferSize: 100000000,
        transports: [Object],
        allowUpgrades: true,
        allowRequest: [Function],
        cookie: 'io',
        ws: [Object],
        _events: [Object] } },
  adapter:
   { nsp:
      { name: '/',
        server: [Object],
        sockets: [Object],
        connected: [Object],
        fns: [],
        ids: 0,
        acks: {},
        adapter: [Circular],
        _events: [Object] },
     rooms: { GLhGYMCy2FAXCYUXAAAA: [Object] },
     sids: { GLhGYMCy2FAXCYUXAAAA: [Object] },
     encoder: {} },
  id: 'GLhGYMCy2FAXCYUXAAAA',
  client:
   { server:
      { nsps: [Object],
        _path: '/socket.io',
        _serveClient: true,
        _adapter: [Function: Adapter],
        _origins: '*:*',
        sockets: [Object],
        eio: [Object],
        engine: [Object] },
     conn:
      { id: 'GLhGYMCy2FAXCYUXAAAA',
        server: [Object],
        upgraded: false,
        readyState: 'open',
        writeBuffer: [Object],
        packetsFn: [Object],
        sentCallbackFn: [],
        request: [Object],
        checkIntervalTimer: null,
        upgradeTimeoutTimer: null,
        pingTimeoutTimer: [Object],
        transport: [Object],
        _events: [Object] },
     encoder: {},
     decoder: { reconstructor: null, _callbacks: [Object] },
     id: 'GLhGYMCy2FAXCYUXAAAA',
     request:
      { _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _maxListeners: 10,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        httpVersion: '1.1',
        complete: false,
        headers: [Object],
        trailers: {},
        _pendings: [],
        _pendingIndex: 0,
        url: '/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1407255549764-3',
        method: 'GET',
        statusCode: null,
        client: [Object],
        _consuming: true,
        _dumped: true,
        httpVersionMajor: 1,
        httpVersionMinor: 1,
        upgrade: false,
        _query: [Object],
        res: [Object],
        cleanup: [Function: cleanup],
        read: [Function] },
     onclose: [Function],
     ondata: [Function],
     ondecoded: [Function],
     sockets: [ [Circular] ],
     nsps: { '/': [Circular] } },
  conn:
   { id: 'GLhGYMCy2FAXCYUXAAAA',
     server:
      { clients: [Object],
        clientsCount: 1,
        pingTimeout: 60000,
        pingInterval: 25000,
        upgradeTimeout: 10000,
        maxHttpBufferSize: 100000000,
        transports: [Object],
        allowUpgrades: true,
        allowRequest: [Function],
        cookie: 'io',
        ws: [Object],
        _events: [Object] },
     upgraded: false,
     readyState: 'open',
     writeBuffer: [ [Object] ],
     packetsFn: [ undefined ],
     sentCallbackFn: [],
     request:
      { _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _events: {},
        _maxListeners: 10,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        httpVersion: '1.1',
        complete: false,
        headers: [Object],
        trailers: {},
        _pendings: [],
        _pendingIndex: 0,
        url: '/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1407255549764-3',
        method: 'GET',
        statusCode: null,
        client: [Object],
        _consuming: true,
        _dumped: true,
        httpVersionMajor: 1,
        httpVersionMinor: 1,
        upgrade: false,
        _query: [Object],
        res: [Object],
        cleanup: [Function: cleanup],
        read: [Function] },
     checkIntervalTimer: null,
     upgradeTimeoutTimer: null,
     pingTimeoutTimer:
      { _idleTimeout: 85000,
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idleStart: 1407255550303,
        _onTimeout: [Function],
        _repeat: false },
     transport:
      { readyState: 'opening',
        maxHttpBufferSize: 100000000,
        supportsBinary: true,
        _events: [Object],
        sid: 'GLhGYMCy2FAXCYUXAAAA',
        req: null,
        res: null,
        writable: false },
     _events: { close: [Object], data: [Function] } },
  rooms: [],
  acks: {},
  connected: true,
  disconnected: false,
  handshake:
   { headers:
      { host: '127.0.0.1:3000',
        connection: 'keep-alive',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (K
HTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36',
        origin: 'http://localhost:8100',
        accept: '*/*',
        referer: 'http://localhost:8100/',
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate,sdch',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4',
        cookie: 'io=caTBp-s8ImeeiAQwAAAE' },
     time: 'Tue Aug 05 2014 09:19:10 GMT-0700 (US Mountain Standard Time)',
     address: { address: '127.0.0.1', family: 'IPv4', port: 3000 },
     xdomain: true,
     secure: false,
     issued: 1407255550308,
     url: '/socket.io/?EIO=2&transport=polling&t=1407255549764-3',
     query: { EIO: '2', transport: 'polling', t: '1407255549764-3' } } }
```

Really hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out why the socket listeners do not work after refresh. 
The angularJS is a single page app, while only the functions defined in corresponding controllers of a specific view will be loaded after refresh. So after the 2nd view is refreshed, it can't load the listeners defined in the first view. That's why the client and server can reconnect but the listeners can't receive the message.

My solution to this problem is to move all the socket listeners to a new controller socketCtrl, and bind it to the body tag, not a particular view.

If add a set of listeners in each view, before refreshing the second view, it will receive each message twice, since there are actually two listeners, one in the first view, one in the second. So this is not a good solution.

I also thought about add those controllers only after refreshing the second view. However it seems very difficult to detect the refreshing, and it is kind of stupid to replicate that large block twice.